# Is it acceptable and grammatical to use more than one "and" when listing phrases?

Tags: grammar

"On the southern section, there was woodland on the south west corner, an IT centre, car park, woodland, **and** grassland along the main road, **and** a cyber security building, which was immediately south of the grassland."

In a way, I grouped the nouns that I wanted to list, so I thought it was acceptable to use two "and"s. Am I correct? Please, explain the answer.

I checked many websites for useful information but found nothing helpful; I guess no one has faced a similar dilemma.

Comment: I find the sentence acceptable, but I had to read it two or three times to work out the exact meaning. I suggest making it into more than one sentence. "Immediately south of the grassland there was a cyber security building."

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is a list within a list.

So you have used the 'and's quite correctly. However, you need a comma after 'and grassland', because otherwise the sentence is very had to parse at one go.

To give an example where you would use even more ands:

*"On the southern section, there was woodland and a cabin, on the south west corner, an IT centre, car park, woodland, and grassland, along the main road, and a cyber security building and ice cream stall, which was immediately south of the grassland."*

(I'm not recommending such a sentence.)